# Wordpress .htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

So I was trying to understand the regex used behind wordpress.

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Can someone please explain to me exactly what this is doing? Keep in mind I am not fluent at all with regex. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want a lesson or do you have an actual issue with your code?

Comment: Well, this code is directly from wordpress. The issue isnt with the code, but what I need to accomplish. This can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429181/custom-htaccess-rules-in-mu-wordpress-site